# How to convert UTC datetime to specific Zone datetime and check is daylight saving

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have UTC datetime for example

```
String dateTime = "2018-04-23 19:50:53.236";
```

I want to convert this into specific TimeZone `US/Eastern`,and then i want to check that converted `datetime` comes under `DaylightSavings`

**TimeZone**

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern");
```

**DaylightSavings Code**

```
ZoneId.of("US/Eastern")
  .getRules()
  .isDaylightSavings( 
      Instant.now() 
  )
```

If `isDaylightSavings` returns true the i have to append offset `(-04:00)` to input `dateTime`

**Sample Output**

```
dateTime = "2018-04-23T19:50:53-04:00"
```

If `isDaylightSavings` returns false the i have to append offset `(-05:00)` to input `dateTime`

**Sample Output**

```
dateTime = "2018-04-23T19:50:53-05:00"
```

I have pieces of code, but i'm confused how to combine all of them, and last question

How to generate current `datetime` f different zone in `UTC` with offset, for example consider  this `US/Eastern`

**Sample Output**

```
dateTime = "2019-01-14T14:12:53-05:00"
```

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, converting the utc date/time to a specific Timezone should automatically apply the daylight savings rules, you’d just need to output the result through an appropriate formatter

Comment: okay, can you show me how to do that? it's not really clear for me @MadProgrammer

Comment: You could have a look at [this blog](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-date-and-time-between-timezone/) for examples for converting between time zones

Comment: Thank you sir, let me take a look @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, this is more automatic than you think.

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

    String dateTime = "2018-04-23 19:50:53.236";
    ZonedDateTime usEasternTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, inputFormatter)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    String formattedDateTime = usEasternTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(formattedDateTime);
```

Output is:

> 2018-04-23T15:50:53.236-04:00

Your requested offset of `-04:00` is output as part of the standard ISO 8601 format. The time output is 15:50:53, where you had asked for 19:50:53. I understood that 19:50:53 was in UTC, and at this UTC time, the time in Eastern USA is 15:50:53 or 4 hours less.

If instead we take a date in winter, we get `-05:00` and the time of day is 5 hours less than the UTC time:

```
    String dateTime = "2018-11-23 19:50:53.236";
```

> 2018-11-23T14:50:53.236-05:00

**EDIT**:

> any idea how to remove milliseconds…

```
    String formattedDateTime = usEasternTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

> 2018-04-23T15:50:53-04:00

(continued)

> …and this `[America/New_York]`

When you print the `ZonedDateTime`, the Zone ID is printed too. Above I use a built-in formatter to control the output. The other option is to convert to `OffsetDateTime`:

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = usEasternTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(odt);
```

> 2018-04-23T15:50:53-04:00

Had the 19:50:53 been in Eastern Time, it would have been still a bit simpler:

```
    ZonedDateTime usEasternTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, inputFormatter)
            .atZone(zone);
```

> 2018-04-23T19:50:53.236-04:00

The current way to identify a time zone is *region/city*, so I use `America/New_York` even though the now deprecated `US/Eastern` still works and produces the same result.

The `TimeZone` class has design problems and is outdated, replaced by `ZoneId`, so just use the latter.

**Link:** [*List of tz database time zones* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: any idea how to remove milliseconds and this `[America/New_York]`, i just need like this`2018-04-23T19:50:53-04:00`

Comment: I added a link at the bottom. In the list each zone ID is marked as either canonical, alias or deprecated, and to the far right is the canonical zone with the same semantics.